# Why does this bash script not exit?

Tags: bash

**Might be a basic question, but I'm not sure why logging would cause this exit function to not work as expected:**

```
#!/bin/bash

function exitFunct
{
  exit 1
}

exitFunct  2>&1 | tee -a /var/tmp/output.txt
echo "You should never see this"
```

But output is "You should never see this"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `man bash` explains,

> Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell).

Therefore, the `exit` in the function exits just the subshell that runs the function's part of the pipeline.

And also,

> The return status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command, unless the `pipefail` option is enabled.

Therefore, you can change the behaviour by prepending

```
set -eo pipefail
```

to the script (`-e` makes your script stop on error). Nonetheless, note that using `exit 0` wouldn't end it.

Comment: Which means that the `exit` in the function is exiting the pipeline-spawned sub-shell and not the parent shell. (Just to make that point clear.)

Comment: @wizurd: If you don't want `grep` to end the script, handle the case in an or: `grep ... || echo Nothing found`